# Something wrong when i used SpelExpressionParser to parse a expression with enum

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-el

Code show as below:

```java
public class SpELTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        context.setVariable("targetType", FavorTargetType.ARTICLE);
        String exp = "#{targetType.getCode()}";
        SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(exp, new TemplateParserContext());
        // SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'targetType' cannot be found on null
        String value = expression.getValue(context, String.class);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum FavorTargetType implements BaseEnum {
    ARTICLE(1, "article"),
    POSTS(2, "posts"),
    COMMENT(3, "comment")
    ;
    private final int code;
    private final String name;
}
public interface BaseEnum {
    @JsonValue
    int getCode();
    String getName();
}
```

When I run the code I will get a SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'targetType' cannot be found on null. But as you can see, targetType is not null. So where am I going wrong? Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: how the getCode get it's value?

Comment: You have to just change `exp` to `#{#targetType.getCode()}`

Answer (score 0):

```
String exp = "#targetType.getCode()";
SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(exp);
EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.setVariable("targetType", FavorTargetType.ARTICLE);
String value = expression.getValue(context, String.class);
System.out.println(value);  // <--- prints out 1
```

Is there a specific reason you were passing `new TemplateParserContext()` to the `parseExpression()` method? Because when you do pass that argument it means you want to parse template and that is not what you are doing in this case.

> Supports parsing templates as well as standard expression strings.

^ Taken from [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/ExpressionParser.html) we can clearly see that this method can be used when parsing both templates and expression strings, you were using the right function with wrong parameters.

Comment: Cool! You are right! In fact, I had spend more than one hour to sovle this bug yesterday, but I dont know what cause it. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

try this it is working

```
package com.example.test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.expression.EvaluationContext;
import org.springframework.expression.Expression;
import org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateParserContext;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;

public class SpELTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        context.setVariable("targetType", FavorTargetType.ARTICLE);
        String exp = "#targetType.getCode()";
        SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(exp);
        // SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'targetType' cannot be found on null
        String value = expression.getValue(context,String.class);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public enum FavorTargetType implements BaseEnum {
        ARTICLE(1, "article"),
        POSTS(2, "posts"),
        COMMENT(3, "comment")
        ;
        private final int code;
        private final String name;
    }
    public interface BaseEnum {
        @JsonValue
        int getCode();
        String getName();
    }

}
```